# Requested Member of Collection Does not Exist - VBA error when copying from array to Word table

Tags: vba, csv, ms-word

I am reading a string from a csv file and trying to print this into respective cells in a word document table. So far I have this, but it keeps throwing the Collections does not exist error:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String

    Open "D:\Users\file2.csv" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, ",")

    For i = 1 To UBound(strData)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(i, 2).Range.Text = strData(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Basically I am taking the ith element of the array and pasting it in the ith row of the second column.

The csv file  has only 1 line (will always have only one line) with 6 fields:

`hello,world,blah,haha,yes,huh`

To be safe (and for testing purposes), my table is an 8x8 table, and it still throws the error on the `ActiveDocument...` line.

To be even safer, I have 2 tables, (just in case my Table number is off (not sure if it begins at 1 or 0)).

Changed the line to:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, i).Range.Text = strData(i - 1)
```

And it works. However the text is only displayed after I close the user form. How do I get the text show upon button click?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a another function after, that I was not using. When I commented out this function, it worked. I still do not know why an unused function would prevent the userform from displaying the entered data, but it works.

Regarding the Collection does not exist error, I changed the line to:
`ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, i).Range.Text = strData(i - 1)` 
and now it works